# how to backup elasticsearch cluster

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, backup-strategies

i have elasticsearch cluster running. as of now there is no backup enabled  till now neither S3 or NAS. we want to upgrade elasticsearch cluster on a new servers and the data size is 100gb of 2 indexes.

since we dont have backup, can we copy the data stored directory from the running cluster on all three nodes to a new cluster will this work?

current running version of `es:6.2.3 to es:6.3.4`
please advice.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In theory copying should work, but no guarantee. There is https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-snapshots.html

Answer (score 0):

Taking a copy of indices folder on the running system of your elasticsearch cluster and restoring on the new es-cluster working fine.

Thanks to @Andreas Volkmann